# SQL for multiple sums and divides under the same query

Tags: sql

We want to extract through a sql query the results from the division of each one of multiple sums divided by their counterpart divider, which is also a sum coming from another column under the same DB.

e.g: sum (cross_border_approved_volume)/ sum (cross_border_transaction_count), then sum (domestic_approved_volume)/ sum (domestic_transaction_count), etc.

I'm trying something like the below, but it doesn't seem to have the correct syntax to do this and I'm not sure what to change.

```
select((select sum(cross_border_approved_volume) as cross_border_approved_volume,
               sum(domestic_approved_volume)     as domestic_approved_volume,
               sum(consumer_approved_volume)     as consumer_approved_volume
        from rmd_owner.ica_dimension_aggregate
        where issuer_id in (41, 42, 43)
          and bin8 = -1
            / (select sum(cross_border_transaction_count) as cross_border_transaction_count,
                      sum(domestic_transaction_count)     as domestic_transaction_count,
                      sum(consumer_transaction_count)     as consumer_transaction_count
               from rmd_owner.ica_dimension_aggregate
               where issuer_id in (41, 42, 43)
                 and bin8 = -1))) as result;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (SQL Server syntax):

```sql
;with cte as (select
    sum(cross_border_approved_volume)   as cross_border_approved_volume,
    sum(domestic_approved_volume)       as domestic_approved_volume,
    sum(consumer_approved_volume)       as consumer_approved_volume,
    sum(cross_border_transaction_count) as cross_border_transaction_count,
    sum(domestic_transaction_count)     as domestic_transaction_count,
    sum(consumer_transaction_count)     as consumer_transaction_count
  from rmd_owner.ica_dimension_aggregate
  where issuer_id in (41, 42, 43) and bin8 = -1  
)
select
  cross_border_approved_volume / cross_border_transaction_count as cross_border_ratio,
  domestic_approved_volume     / domestic_transaction_count     as domestic_approved_ratio,
  consumer_approved_volume     / consumer_transaction_count     as consumer_approved_ratio
from cte
```

The same can be done with subquery:

```sql
select
  cross_border_approved_volume / cross_border_transaction_count as cross_border_ratio,
  domestic_approved_volume     / domestic_transaction_count     as domestic_approved_ratio,
  consumer_approved_volume     / consumer_transaction_count     as consumer_approved_ratio
from (select
    sum(cross_border_approved_volume)   as cross_border_approved_volume,
    sum(domestic_approved_volume)       as domestic_approved_volume,
    sum(consumer_approved_volume)       as consumer_approved_volume,
    sum(cross_border_transaction_count) as cross_border_transaction_count,
    sum(domestic_transaction_count)     as domestic_transaction_count,
    sum(consumer_transaction_count)     as consumer_transaction_count
  from rmd_owner.ica_dimension_aggregate
  where issuer_id in (41, 42, 43) and bin8 = -1  
) x
```

You can also add the `group by` clause if you need these values calculated for groups, e.g. per `issuer_id`.